# How do I determine the descriptor of a given Extended Public Key?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, bitcoin-cli

I am trying to run the `bitcoin-cli getdescriptorinfo` on a `ypub...` extended public key. Every time I do this I receive the message:

`error code: -5
error message:
Invalid descriptor`

How can I determine the correct descriptor for a given ypub?

I am trying to derive the addresses using bitcoin core and import them into my wallet. I am fairly new to using bitcoin-core so I'm not even sure if this is the best way to do this. If not, what other method might I be able to use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does importmulti not support zpub and ypub?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/89261/why-does-importmulti-not-support-zpub-and-ypub)

Comment: I don't have any other info other than the extended public key.

Comment: Someone could probably write a tool to convert ypubs and zpubs to descriptor format. I don't think such a tool exists.