# BTCPayServer - importing wallet using zpub

Tags: wallet, public-key, btcpay

I'm trying to connect my BTCPay server to hardware walet by entering the public key. The HW wallet account is P2WPKH, the public key has a `zpub…` format.

When I enter the key, server correctly generates a `bc1…` address for confirmation, but when I hit the button to confirm, I'm redirected back to the previous page (somewhat modified) with error "Invalid derivation scheme".

This pub key worked on my previous BTCPay instance without any problems. I have no idea what is going on. Any help or insight appreciated!

Running BTCPay Server v1.11.1

[image]

Comment: Hi Gusep, have you tried filing a bug report with BTCPayServer?

Comment: I haven't yet, tried the support chat but still no luck

Comment: I discovered, that I'm not even able to cerate hot wallet. Created a new discussion on btcpayserver github regarding this but still not an inch closer to solution https://github.com/btcpayserver/btcpayserver/discussions/5260

Answer (score 1):

So at the end, there was some part of .NET SDK missing on the system. Managed to pull the log from NBXplorer service.

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel
```

Reinstall of .NET6.0 and rebuild of NBXplorer solved the issues.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a regression introduced in a newer release of BTCPayServer, it's better addressed there. That said, from the screenshot the text input seems to be expecting a descriptor.

`zpub` is just another encoding for an `xpub` which implicitly conveys it is used to derive at specific path for P2WPKH outputs (more about this in [this answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/89281/101498)). Therefore you can just convert your `zpub` to an `xpub` and use a `wpkh(xpub/84'/1'/0'/1/*)` which should derive the same `bc1..` addresses as when using a `zpub`.